# "XXX is an interface and jaxb can't handle interface" error in liferay context only

Tags: jaxb, liferay, cxf, xmlbeans

I use CXF 2.7.5 to call Web services. I generated the client classes with wsdl2java program (in command line MSDOS and in maven). I must use xmlbeans databinding because with jaxb (default databinding) I have some errors, and I can't modify the server side. So with xmlbeans databinding parameter the generation is OK.

I call the web methods with the following method :

```
WcfDemandService service = new WcfDemandService();
IWcfDemandService client = service.getBasicHttpBindingIWcfDemandService();
TODemand ticketToSubmit = TODemand.Factory.newInstance();
```

...

```
boolean ret = client.submit(ticketToSubmit);
```

When I call webmethods, it works perfectly on simple java program, but in portlet liferay context that doesn't work : I have this error (in english, the translation is org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocumen is an interface and jaxb can't handle interfaces) :

09:48:33,899 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-4][PortletServlet:115] javax.portlet.PortletException: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 149 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument est une interface et JAXB ne peut pas gérer les interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument
org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument$CheckConsistency est une interface et JAXB ne peut pas gérer les interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument$CheckConsistency
        at public abstract org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument$CheckConsistency org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument.getCheckConsistency()
        at org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument
org.datacontract.schemas.x2004.x07..TODemand est une interface et JAXB ne peut pas gérer les interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.datacontract.schemas.x2004.x07..TODemand
        at public abstract org.datacontract.schemas.x2004.x07.*****.TODemand org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument$CheckConsistency.getEntity()
        at org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument$CheckConsistency
        at public abstract org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument$CheckConsistency org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument.getCheckConsistency()
        at org.tempuri.CheckConsistencyDocument

This error is repeated for a lot of interfaces.

Do you know why this code doesn't work in liferay context?

Comment: Your model was generated using XMLBeans and that model based on the exception is being interpreted by a JAXB implementation?  What was the original problem you hit with JAXB?

Comment: Yes, I generated with XML beans and I have a jaxb error(but in simple java program, it works).

Comment: The original error I had when I generated the wsdl with jaxb is :
The id property is already defined. use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

The following location matches the above error :
http://*****/WcfDemandService.svc?xsd=xsd2 [0,0]:

Comment: I can help you with that issue if you are interested.

Comment: Yes i am. Have you got this problem (on liferay context)?

Comment: No, but I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead.

Comment: Ok. I created a specific question about the problem with wsdl2java which generates JAXB error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714465/cxf-wsdl2java-the-xx-property-is-already-defined

Comment: The problem was due to one endorsed directory which contained lot of library ; when I deleted it, the error was removed

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using CXF in this case.  The stack trace (com.sun.xml.ws.spi....) shows you are using Metro, not CXF.   Check your classpath and such to make sure you really are using CXF.   CXF should be able to use XMLBeans if you want to stick with that.  (although using a JAXB based solution from Blaise is likely better anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to one endorsed directory which contained lot of library ; when I deleted it, the error was removed

Answer (score 0):

If the classes were generated using `XmlBeans`, then, you may use `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` and explicitly configure to use `XmlBeansDataBinding` since CXF use JAXB default for all its operations.

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(YourServiceInterface.class);
factory.setDataBinding(new XmlBeansDataBinding()); 
factory.setAddress(endPoint);
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor());
```