# CXF - Wsdl2java - the XX property is already defined

Tags: properties, jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java, defined

I use CXF to generate client class to access web service server. The web service are based on WCF (.NET).

When I call wsdl2java, I have the following error :

```
The id property is already defined. use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict. The following location matches the above error : http://*****/WcfDemandService.svc?xsd=xsd2 [0,0]
```

This error does not appear if I ask xmlbeans databinding (use "db xmlbeans" option).

Is there any way to generate classes with JAXB databinding?

Answer (score 8):

This type of problem often occurs when a type has an attribute and element with the same name.

**schema.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="foo">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="bar" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="bar" type="string"/>
        </complexType>
    </element>

</schema>
```

**xjc schema.xsd**

When we try to generate a Java model from this XML schema we get the following error.

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Property "Bar" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 11 of file:/Users/bdoughan/Scratch/src/forum16714465/schema.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 13 of file:/Users/bdoughan/Scratch/src/forum16714465/schema.xsd
```

**binding.xml**

A JAXB binding file can be used to customize the classes that are generated.  Here we will use it to rename the property that will correspond to the `bar` attribute.

```xml
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='foo']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='bar']">
                <jxb:property name="barAttribute"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd**

Now when you generate the Java classes you will get a class like:

```java
package org.example.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "bar"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String bar;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "bar")
    protected String barAttribute;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String value) {
        this.bar = value;
    }

    public String getBarAttribute() {
        return barAttribute;
    }

    public void setBarAttribute(String value) {
        this.barAttribute = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you help find solution for generationg java sources from wsdl [wsimport can't generate java source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893047/wsimport-cant-generate-java-source-error-property-bookingreferenceid-is-a)? it has similar area...